# Adding headers to ListView with LinearLayout, Listview gets pushed off screen (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, xaml, listview, xamarin, layout

As the title says, I want to add some headers to a list view I have displaying addresses. It seems like I can basically choose between my list view displaying on page, or my headers.
In the picture below, I have my headers (4 textviews) in a linear layout. My list view does not display when the linear layout is in my code

[image]

[image]

When I remove my linear layout, my list view appears! My code is below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayoutParent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/swipeLayout">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/headerLinearLayout">
            <TextView
                android:text="Address Line"
                android:id="@+id/headerAddressLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="City"
                android:id="@+id/headerCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="State"
                android:id="@+id/headerState"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Zip Code"
                android:id="@+id/headerZipCode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
                android:paddingTop="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/myListView"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editSearch"
            android:hint="Search ZipCodes"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:editable="false"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried:

- Switching the positioning of my list view to above the linear layout
- Adding an additional linear layout to contain both the headers, and then the list view
- Adding a 2dp height view right above the list view
- Messing around with the heights of the elements, trying different combinations of wrap_content, match_parent, and setting exact heights

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code and description, you can try add one LinearLayout in SwipeRefreshLayout, then adding child element in LinearLayout, like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutParent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/headerLinearLayout">
        <TextView
            android:text="Address Line"
            android:id="@+id/headerAddressLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="City"
            android:id="@+id/headerCity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="State"
            android:id="@+id/headerState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Zip Code"
            android:id="@+id/headerZipCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
           
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myListView"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/editSearch"
        android:hint="Search ZipCodes"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:editable="false"/>
```

The screenshot is:

[image]

I modify editSearch EditText `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`, you can change it as you want.

Comment: Thank you again for the help Cherry! It worked!